# Getting Sidekiq to work with papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq, paper-trail-gem

I try to move all the logging of my rails (3.2.17) app in production and staging to papertrail. Now I'm trying to set the logger for sidekiq in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` like this:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  Sidekiq::Logging.logger = RemoteSyslogLogger.new('logs.papertrailapp.com', ENV.fetch('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'), program: "sidekiq-#{Rails.env}")
end
```

When I try to start sidekiq with:

```
bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile <PATH_TO_PID> --environment staging --daemon
```

I get

```
You really should set a logfile if you're going to daemonize
...bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:141:in `daemonize'
...bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:39:in `parse'
...bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.4/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
...bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
...bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

However if I give sidekiq a dummy for logging first:

```
bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile <PATH_TO_PID> --environment staging --daemon --logfile /dev/null
```

it works like a charm (logs are sent to papertrail), since the initializer seems to override the previous option.

But I find this approach quite ugly. Anybody got a **cleaner approach** to this?

Comment: Does this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058417/sidekiq-server-not-loading-configuration-file) help you?

Comment: Not really, in that case a config file was used. I need to use (at least I don't see another option) an initializer to make it work with papertrail.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed it with the owner of sidekiq and he made a good point: from the time the process is started until the time the initializer has run, a lot of things can go wrong. If the logger is only initialized in the initializer, everything that happended before, won't appear in any log.

I probably will go with the appoach recommended by the sidekiq owner:

```
bundle exec sidekiq | logger -t sidekiq
```